# Ignore a particular column on update trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a PostgreSQL table with 15 columns. I have an `on update` trigger on it. I'd like to exclude `column10` from it. Meaning when there is any update on `column10` only then there should not be any action other than it. If full update or any other column update, trigger should fire as normal.

I don't seem to find any easy way to do this. Can someone suggest please?

Comment: Give us the DDL of the table (`CREATE TABLE foo (...);`) - you can do this using `pg_dump mydb -t mytable --schema-only`! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: See also: [ask]

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation shows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) that you can define specific columns in an `on update` trigger:

```
create trigger foo
after update of column1, column2, ... -- other columns, except column10
on your_table ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem is we have to keep on changing trigger function code whenever table structure changes, meaning if we add col16 then trigger code should be changed to accommodate this. Wondering if there is any easy way to exclude one column instead of using rest of them.                                                                    Is there something like IF NOT UPDATE(column) - we can use in postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by leveraging the `to_jsonb` function.

```
IF (to_jsonb(OLD.*) - 'column10') = (to_jsonb(NEW.*) - 'column10') THEN
```

Per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), the minus sign operator

> Deletes a key (and its value) from a JSON object, or matching string value(s) from a JSON array.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the update of column10 in the trigger function

```
IF OLD.column10 = NEW.column10 THEN
  ... do the trigger stuff ...
ELSE
  ... do nothing, because column10 has been changed
END IF;
```

Comment: Beware NULL values...

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for something like this (for one key):

```
IF
    (row_to_json(OLD)::jsonb - 'column10')
    =
    (row_to_json(NEW)::jsonb - 'column10')
THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'column10 excluded.';
END IF;
```

And for multiple keys:

```
IF
    (row_to_json(OLD)::jsonb #- '{column10}' #- '{columnXYZ}')
    =
    (row_to_json(NEW)::jsonb #- '{column10}' #- '{columnXYZ}')
THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'column10 and columnXYZ excluded.';
END IF;
```

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html